# Application with Accessibility for Blind People

Tags: c#, java, accessibility, google-calendar-api

I am about to start developing an application, which requires accessibility for blind people. It will be a front-end to google calendar for blind people. Can I do this in C#? Does .NET provide accessibility? I want to read the information from screen readers, a software that uses voice to interpret what is written on the screen. Any good suggestions from anyone on where to start? I've only found stuff about web accessibility...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer; yes, Winform and Web controls have Accessibility properties which are reported to accessibility clients like screen readers. You'll need to ensure that all these have proper data specified (there are no meaningful default values given).

Comment: Thank you mery much for you quick answer! I've read a lot about accessibility in Java. Are you aware of this? Would you recommend me to use C# or Java? I'm in the research stage at the moment, that's why I'm asking... Thanks again! :-)

Comment: If it were me, I'd write it in C#, but that's what I develop in on a day-to-day basis, so I'm biased. I'm sure you'll find several staunch defenders of Java in this case as well.